# DateField in DRF django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've a model which have a DateField.

```
class A(model.Model):
    a = model.DateField()


class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = (a,)
```

The payload that I pass have a chance that it might send only year, for eg:-

```
{
    "a": "1991"
}
```

It returns an error saying,

```
"Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
```

I'm already passing one the format, as mentioned in the error, but still I'm getting an error.

Why?

Comment: "1991" is not a valid date , try to pass "1991-01-01"

Comment: That works. However, I want to test it for `1991`.

Comment: It'll not pass through the serializer validators , try to declare `a` as a `TextField` inside the serializer , then convert it to Date in the save method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simple solutions will be, define `field a` as separate in your serializer and provide sufficient values to the `input_formats`  argument

```
required_formats = ['%Y', '%d-%m-%Y']  # add other formats you need


class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = serializers.DateField(input_formats=required_formats)

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('a',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all needed date formats to variable `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in `settings.py`, for example:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']
```

Comment: What should be the case when only year is expected.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast, does just `['%Y']` work? If it doesn't, try setting `USE_L10N = False`, as according to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#date-input-formats):  When USE_L10N is True, the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead.